# Does the US Consulate know visa overstays?

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration

What type of database does the US Consulate has access to? Do they know overstays? If so can they decide visa issuance based on that information?
I just got a tourist visa but not quite sure if I have overstayed previous visa since I had D/S. Will I get stopped at the port of entry?

Comment: Hi! What makes you think you overstayed previously? Do you believe you were out of status?

Comment: How did your previous status end, and how long did you remain in the US after it ended?

Answer (score 4):

The US Consulate has access to all kinds of databases that we do not know about.

> Do they know overstays?

They can find out if suspicious and they check. Obviously people have been issued with visas in error despite previously overstaying and having a ban. Many times those people are apprehended by immigration at the port of entry.

> but not quite sure if I have overstayed previous visa since I had D/S.

D/S non-immigrants can overstay although they do not start accumulating [unlawful presence](https://www.cilawgroup.com/news/2009/05/15/when-does-unlawful-presence-start/).

> Nonimmigrants Admitted for Duration of Status (D/S).  If USCIS finds a
>   nonimmigrant status violation while adjudicating a request for an
>   immigration benefit, unlawful presence will begin to accrue on the day
>   after the request is denied.   Similarly, if an immigration judge
>   makes a determination of nonimmigrant status violation in exclusion,
>   deportation or removal proceedings, unlawful presence begins to accrue
>   the day after the immigration judge’s order or the day after the Form
>   I-94 expired, whichever comes first.  Note that accrual of unlawful
>   presence does not begin on the date that a status violation occurs,
>   nor does it begin on the day on which removal proceedings are
>   initiated.

So basically if in your case USCIS did not find an immigration violation or you never went before an immigration judge, you did not accrue unlawful presence. However student with D/S are supposed to leave within a set number of days of [grace period](https://isss.gsu.edu/current-students/immigration-advising/grace-periods/).You could be stopped and denied entry at the port of entry if the immigration officer determines this.

> If you are an F-1 student and have withdrawn from classes after
>   receiving authorization from ISSS, you have 15 days to leave the U.S.
>
> If you have withdrawn from classes without previous authorization, you
>   have no grace period and must leave the U.S. immediately.
>
> If you are an F-1 student and have completed your program of study,
>   you have 60 days to leave the United States, apply for change of
>   status, or transfer to another school. Note that this does NOT apply
>   if you do not complete your program; if you leave without graduating,
>   you do not receive a grace period.
>
> If you are a J-1 student and have completed your program objective,
>   you have 30 days to leave the United States or change to another visa
>   status.  Note that this does NOT apply if you do not complete your
>   program objective; if you leave without completing your program
>   objective, you do not receive a grace period.

**Revision 8/8/2018**

> U.S. Citizenship and Immigration Services (USCIS) today posted a
>   policy memorandum (PDF, 179 KB)[changing how the agency will calculate
>   unlawful presence for students and exchange visitors in F, J, and M
>   nonimmigrant
>   status](https://www.uscis.gov/news/news-releases/uscis-changing-policy-accrued-unlawful-presence-nonimmigrant-students-and-exchange-visitors),
>   including F-2, J-2, or M-2 dependents, who fail to maintain their
>   status in the United States.
>
> **The day after they no longer pursue the course of study or the authorized activity, or the day after they engage in an unauthorized
>   activity;**

Comment: It might be more accurate to say that 'You could be stopped and **refused entry** at the port of entry," rather than deported.